# ajax request not working on changing network connection in phonegap (cross domain)

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

The ajax request is working fine with one network but as i switch to some other wireless network it does'nt work. I am trying to load data from cross domain. This issue is only on the android version. I am using phonegap version 2.0.0 .

```
var formdata = $('#login-form').serialize();

var reqUrl = 'http://www'+ domain +'/tokens.json'

var req = $.ajax({
                url: reqUrl,
                data: formdata,
                type: 'POST', 
                dataType: 'json'
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either [traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/traceview.html) or [ARO](http://developer.att.com/developer/legalAgreementPage.jsp?passedItemId=9700312) to track down where the problem is occurring, these will both allow you to analyze network activity. It is possible the connection is being closed when it changes, ARO will allow you to see what is happening and hopefully help you resolve the issue.